# How to pause App Scripts until spreadsheet finishes calculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Because google spreadsheets does not support iterations, I wrote my own simple app script to adjust an input based upon the calculation of the spreadsheet output. However, after I change the input variable, the spreadsheet recalculates but app scripts does not seem to wait for that recalculation so I end up retrieving values such as "Thinking..." or "#NA". Is there a way to pause a script and wait for the calculation to complete before moving to the next line in the script?

Currently, I am just using a loop to watch the cell but I wanted to find out if there was a more elegant way to pause the execution until the sheet was done calculating.

I write a lot of Excel Macros and Excel VBA always waits for the calculation to complete before moving to the next line in the code. Apps Script does not seem to do this so I am hoping there is an easy way to do this.

A second question: Because this iteration can take some time, how does one interrupt and terminate a script from running? I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a very simple way of preventing the next script from starting until the current script completes in google apps scripts. Just add a call for testWait() after each script you are processing successively. The SpreadsheetApp.flush() also seems to reset the timeout timer on the spreadsheet back to the default 5min so you have more time to process multiple scripts in one go.

```
//holds processing of next script till last one has completed
function testWait(){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock(); lock.waitLock(300000); 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); lock.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: In my case just calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` was enough. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I solved with SpreadsheetApp.flush(); as well

Answer (score 5):

Scripts timeout after about 6 minutes to prevent infinite loops and constantly running programs. I don't think there's a manual way to stop a script.

Edit: Oops, forgot to answer your first question: I thought onEdit ran after values were recalculated, but apparently I don't use enough formulas to see this. If it's not waiting, then the best way is to do something like this:

```
while(value === "Thinking..." || value === "#NA") {
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
}
```

It pauses the script for a few seconds and then checks again.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, for anyone looking at this sort of setup for production code outside of Sheets then it's worth adding a sanity check counter (exit the while loop if the counter hits some largeish value) since if for some reason this never completes it locks up a thread forever. I've seen such code bring down servers when they've slowly locked out every thread...

Answer (score 3):

I also write a bit in Excel VBA, where the native Calculation functions come in handy. I've run across the same problem in Google Apps/Docs several times, wanting to execute code whenever calculations are complete.  I wonder why there's no native function in Google Apps/Docs to handle this.  Anyhow, I wrote this code to solve the problem.  Hope it helps.

```
function onEdit() {

Refresh();

};

function Refresh () {

     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
     var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

     // set the range wherever you want to make sure loading is done    

     var range = sheet.getRange('A:A')
     var values = range.getValues();

     var string = values.toString();

     var loading = "Loading";

     do{
       var randomWait = Math.floor(Math.random()*1+0); randomWait;
     } while (string.search(loading) ==! 0);
     range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A1'), {contentsOnly:true});
     customMsgBox();
};

function customMsgBox() {
  Browser.msgBox("Data refreshed.");
};
```

Here's an example in action:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkK50_KKCI_pdHJvQXdnTmpiOWM4Rk5PV2k5OUNudVE#gid=0

Make a copy if you want to play around with it.

Comment: That looks like a fairly intensive busy wait to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting Surely it would be better to use a Utilities.sleep(X) in the loop? Also the example sheet doesn't use the code shown above any more but uses a SpreadsheetApp.flush(); (which doesn't actually work).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, over the past 10 years, the Google Sheets UI must have changed in ways that make this answer not relevant anymore. When I click into the example and look for MENU BAR > ACTIONS > REFRESH, I don't see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by using 2 scripts as I needed to be sure the spreadsheet has the data I need.

The first script provides a seed value to populate the spreadsheet through a IMPORTXML function.

The second script processes this data.

I used time based triggers to run the scripts allowing for sufficient time for the first script to complete

Answer (score 1):

now you can use the  [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?#flush) I [discovered this in this link here](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/k4b31h/how_to_make_google_script_wait_until_sheets_is/?rdt=45189)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the recursive structure in the code.js file, rather than on the spreadsheet. Javascript can handle recursion really well. You could then have the script update the spreadsheet on each iteration (or each 100).