# Google appscipt - Exporting multiple PDF with a for loop, using a sheet as a template, unexpected result

Tags: for-loop, pdf-generation

I'm trying to automate the pdf export of a sheet ('BL') which is filled depending on a cell value grabbed on a variable list on sheet 'EiBLdata' by 'i' on each loop.
It seems to work... more or less.

Instead of having 1st pdf with 1st value,
2nd pdf with 2nd value,
3rd pdf with 3rd value etc.

I get 1st pdf with 1st value,
2nd pdf with 1st value,
3rd pdf with 2nd value etc.

In the end only the 1st pdf has the right name, there is a shift in all the others and the last value isn't exported.

I'm quite a newbie with JavaScript and I admit there is a lot of copy/paste in my code, adapted to my purpose. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function printSelectedRange() {
  
  var nomfeuille = "EiBLData"
  var nomBL = "BL"
  var cc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var feuille = cc.getSheetByName(nomfeuille);
  var BL = cc.getSheetByName(nomBL);
  var tr = BL.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var plage = feuille.getRange('A1:A15').getValues();
  var cell0 = feuille.getRange(1,1).getValue();
    
  BL.getRange('B2').setValue(cell0);
     
 for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    var cell = feuille.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if (cell > 0) {
 
       BL.getRange('B2').setValue(cell)
  
  var sheetName = "BL";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
 

    var ssUrl = ss.getUrl();
    var sheetId= sheet.getSheetId();
   
    var url = ssUrl.replace(/\/edit.*$/,'')
      + '/export?exportformat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=A6'
      + '&portrait=false'
      + '&fitw=false'
      + '&scale=4'
      + '&top_margin=0.35'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.00'          
      + '&left_margin=0.35'             
      + '&right_margin=0.0'           
      + '&sheetnames=false'
      + '&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'
      + '&gid='+sheetId;

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
  var pdf = docurl.getAs('application/pdf');
     
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);

  var docId = sheet.getRange('F13').getValue();
  var clientName =  sheet.getRange('E9').getValue();
  var docDate = sheet.getRange('F14').getValue();
      

  var mois = docDate.getMonth()
  docDate.setMonth((mois+1) % 12); 
 
  var docDateMMYY = docDate.getMonth()+"-"+docDate.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
  var docName = "BL-"+docId+"-"+clientName+"-"+docDateMMYY ;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  var finalFile = file.makeCopy(docName,folder);
  file.setTrashed(true);  
             };
  };
var cmdes = ss.getSheetByName('cmdes');
 var raz = cmdes.getRange('S2:S501').setValue(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a good intuition and finally found the reason of my issue:
[how-to-pause-app-scripts-until-spreadsheet-finishes-calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711072/how-to-pause-app-scripts-until-spreadsheet-finishes-calculation)
It looks like the loop runs faster than the spreadsheet calculation.
Sorry for inconvenience...